# check if a string has specified structure in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have an array of strings and I want to check whether any of my strings has a specified structure or not. for example one of my structures is like this:

```
The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
```

how can I do this in C#?

Comment: Note that this will break quickly if `{0} == H'e'l'l'o`...

Comment: how? Please help me doing this :)

Comment: Try doing some basic research, there is loads of information on regex just search for it.

Comment: "one of my structures"... without all required information it would be impossible to make a complete answer. SO is not here to do the work for you, it is to help with *existing* problems. Please show what you have tried and researched to solve the problem already (as well as what hasn't worked and *why* it hasnt)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with Regex (something I think is like playing with fire), you could...

```
public static Regex MakeRegex(string str)
{
    // We temporarily replace the {x} with \0
    str = string.Format(str, "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0");

    // Then we escape the regex, so that for example the . is changed
    // to \.
    str = Regex.Escape(str);

    // We replace the \0 we had added in the beginning with .*
    str = str.Replace("\0", ".*");

    // We add the ^ and $ to anchor the regex
    str = "^" + str + "$";

    // The regex is complete
    return new Regex(str);
}
```

then

```
Regex rx = MakeRegex("The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.");
bool ismatch = rx.IsMatch("The value '1' is not valid for Foo.");
```

Note that I don't think it is really a good idea... but some persons like to play with fire.

You should cache the `rx` you built with `MakeRegex` if you want to reuse it multiple times.

From some mini-benchmarks I've done, I noticed that `".*?"` could be a little faster than `".*"` (you change the `str.Replace`)...